# ggtern error "Computation failed in `stat_density_tern()"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I'm trying plotting "Density Patterns" for some data but I get an error.

```
TX = data$PositiveFeelings.wertgesch
TY = data$PositiveFeelings.verbunden
TZ = data$PositiveFeelings.sicher
ggtern(data=data, aes(x=TX , y=TY, z=TZ)) + geom_density_tern()
```

I get this ugly warning and error:

> Warning messages:
>   1: stat_density_tern: You have not specified a below-detection-limit (bdl) value (Ref. 'bdl' and 'bdl.val' arguments in ?stat_density_tern). Presently you have 1x value/s below a detection limit of 0.010, which acounts for 9.091% of your data. Density values at fringes may appear abnormally high attributed to the mathematics of the ILR transformation. 
>   You can either:
>   1. Ignore this warning,
>   2. Set the bdl value appropriately so that fringe values are omitted from the ILR calculation, or
>   3. Accept the high density values if they exist, and manually set the 'breaks' argument 
>      so that the countours at lower densities are represented appropriately. 
>   2: Computation failed in `stat_density_tern()`:
>   unused argument (z.range = c(6.93591401660315e-213, 8424.28848000516))

I'm using RStudio Version 1.3.959, R 4.0.1, ggtern 3.3.0 in windows.

Comment: I think ggtern is not compatible with ggplot2 v3.3.0, have you tried with ggplot2 v3.2.1?

Comment: Yes, But I get this error "Error: package ‘ggplot2’ 3.2.1 was found, but >= 3.3.0 is required by ‘ggtern’"... so now I tried with ggtern 3.2.1 and ggplot2 3.2.1 and I get results without any problem. Thanks